# How can I link a button in iOS to change an array for a list view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Not sure if the above is even my question as I am basically new to using objective-c and iOS and not sure if that's the right wording but anyway...

Basically I have completed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITUI7fukRO8 for using a tableView with an array of data.

The substance of the program consists of a navcontroller, tableviewController and a viewController for the extra detail of the table data.

Currently I have a button (from another viewcontroller) that is linking to my tableView. 
How would I go about setting up and IF statement in regards to the button pressed *(-as I need to link other buttons from other controllers)* so that if a specific button is pressed, the array that is displayed in the tableView is different.

I'm currently thinking of doing a bunch of if, then, else statements and just manually changing the detail of the arrays.

Is this the way to go?? 
Or should I just set up another table view for each of my buttons.

I have a set of .h and .m for the tableCell, tableCellController, and the ViewController.

That probably didn't make a whole lot of sense but if you somewhat understand help would be appreciated. 
Cheers

---

Edit: As you can see my code is pretty 'all over the shop' at the moment. I haven't included the Cell View controllers as I don't think they have that much relevance with what I want to do at this stage.The buttonviewcontroller is just a normal UIViewController and both buttons are linked as 'Button1'class in the storyboard. They have been given tags 0 and 1 which I believe is in under the 'view' subheading in the storyboard. Please alert me if this is wrong and I am missing something really obvious but that was the only place I could find 'tag'. ARRRG Objective-c is frustrating when you don't the language at all./
Updated Code as 21/03.

ButtonViewController.M (this is where the buttons are)

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "tableViewController.h"
    #import "TableCell.h"

    @interface ButtonViewController : UIViewController

    -(IBAction) button_Clicked:(id)sender;


    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;

    @end
```

ButtonViewController.m

```
   #import "ButtonViewController.h"
   #import "tableViewController.h"
   #import "TableCell.h"

   @interface ButtonViewController ()

   @end


   @implementation ButtonViewController

   -(IBAction) button_Clicked:(id)sender
{

//something here that is going wrong

tableViewController *tableVC = [[tableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:nil];

    if(_Button1.tag==0)
    {
    tableVC.buttonSelected = 0;
    }

    else if(_Button1.tag==1)
    {
    tableVC.buttonSelected = 1;
    }



[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
    [tableVC.tableView reloadData];

@end
```

tableViewController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface tableViewController : UITableViewController

    @property (nonatomic, assign) int buttonSelected;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
     //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
     //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Description;
    //Not sure if Mutable or normal array
    @end
```

tableViewController.m

```
    #import "tableViewController.h"
    #import "TableCell.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "ButtonViewController.h"

    @interface tableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation tableViewController

       - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
          {
           self = [super initWithStyle:style];
             if (self) {
             // Custom initialization
             }
           return self;
          }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {

    [super viewDidLoad];

      if(_buttonSelected == 0)
    {
        _Title = @[@"Hamstring Muscle Tear",@"Lower Back Pain"];
        _Description = @[@"Blahahaha", @"blahahaha2",@"blalalala3"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];          
    }

    else if (_buttonSelected == 1)
    {
        _Title = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];
        _Description = @[@"dededdededde", @"deddedede2",@"blalalala3"];
          [self.tableView reloadData];
    }



     #pragma mark - Table view data source
     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {

      // Return the number of sections.
      return 1;
        } 

       - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
      {

       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return _Title.count;
       }

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

         int row = [indexPath row];

         cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
          cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];

         return cell;
         }
       -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

       if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

       int row = [myIndexPath row];
       detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row]];
       }

        }
      @end
```

Comment: Can you add the code of what you are doing so far. Also look at the sender from the button and how to use this in connection with tags to identify the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a CTRL - drag in Storyboard to create a IBAction for the button.

In the IBAction method, get the data you want for your data arrays (Images, Title, Description ref the tutorial you linked). Then call:

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

This will repopulate the tableview.

Comment: Do I need to put this in a new viewcontroller or can I put it in the tableview?

Comment: You create the IBAction in the ViewController where the button is included. If the button is in a different ViewController you need access to the arrays that holds your data, and the tableview to refresh. I would suggest implementing a [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Comment: Still having a bit of trouble, I decided to try and assign the buttons a tag and then depending on the tag display different data. Above is my new edit code. It seems to be working up until the point where it loads the data. I've tried swapping a lot of things around but I just seem to be burying my head deeper into the sand. 1st can I do it this way? I read a similar question on here that did it this way. Otherwise will the segue identifier way be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't quite remember, but I think perhaps viewDidLoad can get called when you initiate the tableViewController. That means that your code for checking which button is pressed runs before you change the button.

Also I would **not** call `[self.tableView reloadData]` from `viewDidLoad`. You could try calling the check on _buttonSelected from `viewWillAppear`.

Personally I would recommend segues and set the datasource in `prepareForSegue`.